# [path]isn't a Gem::Specification (NilClass instead)

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i created a test project, and while bundle installing the gems i got an error. then i did a version check of the gem and i got the same error.

```
$ gem -v

[/home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/treetop-1.4.11.gemspec] isn't a Gem::Specification (NilClass instead).
[/home/bharath/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/uglifier-1.3.0.gemspec] isn't a Gem::Specification (NilClass instead).
```

what seems to be the problem.? is it got to do with the version of ruby i am using?

Comment: the trouble was with cache... i suffered a power outage causing the problem. here this [link](http://www.tweetegy.com/2011/04/installing-rails-gem-fails-with-undefined-method-spec-for-nilnilclass-error/) helped me solve the problem

Comment: Google's cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.tweetegy.com/2011/04/installing-rails-gem-fails-with-undefined-method-spec-for-nilnilclass-error/